# Python regex to identify two consecutive capitalized words at the beginning of the line

Tags: python, regex

I have this piece of text from which I want to remove both occurrences of each of the names, "Remggrehte Sertrro" and "Perrhhfson Forrtdd". I tried applying this regex: `([A-Z][a-z]+(?=\s[A-Z])(?:\s[A-Z][a-z]+)+)` but it identifies "Remggrehte Sertrro We", "Perrhhfson Forrtdd If" and also "Mash Mush" which is inside the text.
Basically I want it to only identify first two capitalized words at the beginning of the line without touching the rest. I am no regex expert and I am not sure how to adapt it.

This is the text:

Remggrehte Sertrro

Remggrehte Sertrro We did want a 4-day work week for years.

Perrhhfson Forrtdd

Perrhhfson Forrtdd If drumph does n't get sufficient testing and PPE gear , the economy Mash Mush will continue to.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: What is your expected result?

Comment: Do you mean `^[A-Z][a-z]+\s[A-Z][a-z]+(?!\S)` https://regex101.com/r/NZM2Fd/1

Comment: @LaurentLAPORTE sorry for not being clear, I want to remove each occurrence of both names. So both the one which is on it's own on the newline and also the second one which is, again, at the beginning of a newline.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You don't need the positive lookahead to match the first 2 capitalized words.

In your pattern, this part `(?=\s[A-Z])` can be omitted as your first assert it and then directly match it.

---

You could match the first 2 words without a capturing group and assert a whitespace boundary `(?!\S)` at the right

```
^[A-Z][a-z]+[^\S\r\n][A-Z][a-z]+(?!\S)
```

**Explanation**

- `^` Start of string
- `[A-Z][a-z]+` Match a char A-Z and 1+ lowercase chars a-z
- `[^\S\r\n]` Match a whitespace char except a newline as `\s` could also match a newline and you want to match two consecutive capitalized words at the beginning of the line
- `[A-Z][a-z]+` Match a char A-Z and 1+ lowercase chars a-z
- `(?!\S)` Assert a whitespace boundary at the right

[Regex demo](https://regex101.com/r/mNCCBk/1)

**Note** that `[A-Z][a-z]+` matches only chars a-z. To match word characters you could use `\w` instead of `[a-z]` only.

Comment: one more question, I just noticed that I have a trailing whitespace at the end of some lines which contain only the name and the regex does not take those names into consideration. How could I include that situation to this regex if possible?

Comment: Do you have an example string? You could also update the regex101 link at the left top and send it in the comment. To match a single name https://regex101.com/r/LW9roL/1

Comment: Or use the `\s` to also match a newline https://regex101.com/r/FR297r/1

Comment: I solved it eventually in my script! Thanks a lot though

Answer (score 1):

You can use this pattern `/^([A-Z]+.*? ){2}/m` if you are always certain that you are getting **only two terms** with capitalised first letters and **always in the first two terms** inline. [Example working on regex101.com](https://regex101.com/r/7Y3w2E/1)

Answer (score 0):

You can remove the line which only contains the names using `re.MULTILINE` flag and the following regex: `r"^(?:[A-Z]\w+\s+[A-Z]\w+\s+)$"`. This regex will match each name only if it fits in the line without extra text.

Here is a demo:

```py
import re

text = """\
Remggrehte Sertrro

Remggrehte Sertrro We did want a 4-day work week for years.

Perrhhfson Forrtdd

Perrhhfson Forrtdd If drumph does n't get sufficient testing and PPE gear , the economy Mash Mush will continue to.
"""

print(re.sub(r"^(?:[A-Z]\w+\s+[A-Z]\w+\s+)$", "", text, flags=re.MULTILINE))
```

You get:

```
Remggrehte Sertrro We did want a 4-day work week for years.


Perrhhfson Forrtdd If drumph does n't get sufficient testing and PPE gear , the economy Mash Mush will continue to.
```